# T-SQL XML Out by Command Prompt

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to copy one table to a file out by command prompt. I am using the code below and retrieving the following errors. I am waiting for help from experienced users

I am trying to bulk copy the table `tblDepartment`, from the database `varmieger` to the file `D:\udemy\mydata.out.txt`

This is the code I tried on the command prompt:

```
D:\udemy>BCP [varmieger].dbo.tblDepartment out D:\udemy\mydata.out.txt  -N -T
```

These are the errors which I couldn't have any progress to figure out:

> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>
> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

My operation system is Windows 10 Home edition and I use SQL Server 2014 Express.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell bcp where the server is.  For example,

`BCP [varmieger].dbo.tblDepartment out D:\udemy\mydata.out.txt -N -T -S SqlServerComputer`

You have the `-T` option so hopefully your Windows login will be trusted.  Otherwise you may need to use `-U` and `-P`.